# How to show the google analytic Dashboard in own web site

Tags: php, api, google-analytics, google-analytics-api, google-analytics-sdk

can we show the google analytic Dashboard object in own website by using PHP and  API or oauth?

Comment: did you try this >> https://developers.google.com/analytics/

Comment: I did but I think I didn't integrate this properly.

Comment: i think you can access data sent by the api, but they are not providing their dashboard plugins. you can access the api and integrate it according to your way.

Comment: Can You give any google analytics documentation link?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cant embedded the true Google analytics website in your site there would be no way to login.   However you could create your own version of it.

You can use the [Google Analytics API](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/reporting/core/v4/) and the php client library to create your own dashboard.  I have seen it done well using [charts and graphs](https://developers.google.com/chart/)

An alternative would be the [Embeded API](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/reporting/embed/v1/) this is javascript based though and only works with the core reporting api V3.  It also does not support service accounts.

Comment: Not sure i understand your comment but.  If you put up your application on your website it will be live.  You understand you will have to develop this yourself the API will only give you access to the data it will not display it for you.

Comment: Okay, I will try on my end I think this is helpful thanks.

Comment: @DalmTo can you tell how i can get the developer key

Comment: you should follow this https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/reporting/core/v4/quickstart/web-php

Comment: @DalmTo i am getting this error 
'Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'InvalidArgumentException' with message 'file does not exist' in C:\xampp\htdocs\google_ana\vendor\google\apiclient\src\Google\Client.php:839 Stack trace: #0 C:\xampp\htdocs\google_ana\index.php(9): Google_Client->setAuthConfig('C:\\xampp\\htdocs...') #1 {main} thrown in C:\xampp\htdocs\google_ana\vendor\google\apiclient\src\Google\Client.php on line 839'

Comment: please open a new question.   remember to add your code and the error.

Comment: I honestly don't see the point of creating such a endlessly kinds of dashboards with templating and a whole community for creating and sharing them and in the end, when developers try to use one of those dashboard designs to embed it in an admin website they just can't. It feels like a dead end after creating a dashboard they think they would use.